# Right Side align without float

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a chat widget that I am adding some styling to.  However I am having difficulty making the "user" chat bubbles align to the right of the screen.

When I use float right, with float left(for the other side) the divs no longer position correctly, in that they seem to just go to the right of the relative divs.

I would like it to also be able to append div's that will cause the overflow-y to create a scroll bar. Which without the float is already working as expected.

Below is the current version in a jsbin.

http://jsbin.com/utulay/1/edit

TLDR; trying to get the .chat-bubble-user divs to align to right of screen without float.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

if you don't want use floats, just try with `inline-block`, like so:

```
#chatWindow {
   text-align: right;
}

.chat-bubble-user {
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: left; 
}
```

JsBin (tested on Fx20): http://jsbin.com/awimev/2/edit

Comment: `inline-block` will cause the element to be considered as text. And so, spacing between characters is added, as if the entire element was just regular text. This is not viable if your layout requires pixel perfect positioning.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `float:right` on the user messages and put a clearfix `div` after each one:

http://jsbin.com/utulay/2/edit

```
<div class="chat-bubble-user">
    <div class="chat-bubble-glare-user"></div>
    <p>I have a question about kittens?</p>
    <div class="chat-bubble-arrow-border-user"></div>
    <div class="chat-bubble-arrow-user"></div>
 </div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}
.clearfix {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: just amazing. helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

it has been a problem for sometime until.
You only have to use

```
text-align:right;
display-inline:block;
```

all in the parent member;