# How change the default bootstrap required fields styles

Tags: html, css, validation

I want to change the default bootstrap required fields styles.

I have done well changing the default text using following

I want to change validation message background colour and border colour. How can Change default styles in bootstrap `required` filelds.

Comment: Please refer to these stackoverflow links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713405/how-do-you-style-the-html5-form-validation-messages and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30182676/how-to-style-the-html5-form-validation-messages. Apparently changing validation message bubble background color and border colour is not widely supported in many browsers.

Answer (score 0):

you can add new class to your element but with !important in front of

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read How to Answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer